# How to create a pandas dataframe of first valid values of another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe of the form:

**df**

```
    ID    col_1    col_2    col_3
     1              20       40
     1     10                      
     1     50                60
     3     40       10       90
     4              80       80
```

I am trying to create a new dataframe such that every row corresponds to a unique ID and the columns are the first valid values for the given ID, col combination in the original dataframe

Here's what I'm trying to construct:

**new_df**

```
    ID    first_col_1    first_col_2    first_col_3
    1         10             20             40 
    3         40             10             90 
    4                        80             80
```

I'm trying to use pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index() for this but am unable to combine it with the groupby function that would be required. What is the most pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: `df.groupby('ID').first()`

Comment: That does not work as it just takes the first row. For example, first_col_1 would not be set to 10 for ID=1

Comment: Are the empty rows `NaN`? If they are, then no, 10 would be chosen.  If they are *not* NaN, make them NaN

Comment: Are the cells blank?

Comment: Were not originally NaN, but made them and it worked. Thanks

Comment: If the cells are blank, then try this: `df[df.astype(bool)].groupby('ID').first()`

Comment: I have a followup question, information for which I realize should have been provided earlier. The original dataframe has a 'DateTime' column. I want to be able to have the datatimes for every first valid value of the columns, appended as new columns next to these ones. Should I post this as a separate question?

Comment: I've posted the followup question in case anyone is interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53661605/how-to-merge-columns-after-groupby-and-selecting-first-valid-value-of-other-colu

Answer (score 2):

I think I deserve a `+1` for reconstructing your data ;D

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create DataFrame
rows = []
rows.append({'ID': 1, 'col_1': ' ', 'col_2':'20', 'col_3': '40'})
rows.append({'ID': 1, 'col_1': '10', 'col_2': ' ', 'col_3': ' '})
rows.append({'ID': 1, 'col_1': '50', 'col_2':' ', 'col_3': '60'})
rows.append({'ID': 3, 'col_1': '40', 'col_2':'10', 'col_3': '90'})
rows.append({'ID': 4, 'col_1': ' ', 'col_2':'80', 'col_3': '80'})
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)

#Clean it by replacing whitespaces with nan
clean_df = df.replace(r'\s+', np.nan, regex=True)

# Group on ID and take the first
clean_df.groupby('ID').first()

print(clean_df)
```